# ignore a property at object mapper level?

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have a domain object that gets deserialized either thru Spring MVC or an internal object mapper in my service layer. I need to ignore the input of 1 field when it is being deserialized thru Spring MVC, but not with the internal object mapper in service layer. Is it doable?

Any hints/clues are deeply appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason why can't you use `@JsonIgnore`?

Comment: actually there is another situation that requires me to know which path of deserialization is triggered. can that be done?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Hi, Darshan, wouldn't that make the field not get deserialized with my internal object mapper in service layer? I still need the field deserializable at that time

Comment: Okay, so you want it to get deserialized with internal object mapper but not somewhere else? As I said, an example would be great.

Comment: the same domain object is used by 2 object mappers. Spring MVC uses object mapper 1, and the service layer uses object mapper 2. I only want that field in the domain object to be deserializable with object mapper 2, not object mapper 1

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `Mixin` annotations, (documentation [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)). You can create another class with `@JsonIgnore` field and configure in your internal `objectMapper`, e.g.:

```
abstract class MixIn {
   @JsonIgnore int getXXX(); 
}
```

`objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Model.class, MixIn.class)`;

You can configure this in service layer `objectMapper` which would mean your external `objectMapper` would still be able to serialize/deserialize that field.